# Download file from JSON request using wget

Tags: linux, bash, wget

I am trying to download the latest `just` binary file and I am able to do it with the following line of code in bash:

```
wget -q $(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/casey/just/releases/latest | python -c 'import json,sys;print(json.load(sys.stdin)["assets"][-1]["browser_download_url"])')
```

This works, but I am using `curl` and `wget` together which I feel looks wrong. Is there a way to do this with just `wget`?

Comment: I see nothing wrong

Comment: Since you are already using inline python to parse the initial JSON response, you could implement all of this in python.

Comment: You can replace the wget with curl or vis versa, yes. Just have to use the appropriate options for whichever you choose.

Comment: `wget -q "$(wget -qO- https://api.github.com/repos/casey/just/releases/latest | python -c 'import json,sys;print(json.load(sys.stdin)["assets"][-1]["browser_download_url"])')"` would be more correct with the missing double quotes fixed, and sticking to `wget`. Apart from that, it looks ok. You could do it entirely in Python as Suggested, but it would probably be more verbose. Shell is often appropriate to solve such bolt-on problems with piping and cobbling tools rather than writing a whole in one dedicated tool that needs to deal with low level stuffs like HTTP, transactions, parsing.

Comment: Sometimes cobbling tools with shell can save writing boilerplate code, This is one good use of the shell.

Comment: @j_b I would love to do this in complete bash, but grep and regular expressions goes over my head

Comment: Python is a much more appropriate tool for parsing JSON than `grep`.  Further the suggestion by @knittl to use `jq` would also be a good option for parsing JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wget URL` is the mostly the same as `curl -O URL`.

`curl` is mostly the same as `wget -o- URL`.

But since you are already using python, why not initiate the HTTP request directly from python?

Or instead of using python, use [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) to extract the relevant bits from the JSON:

```
curl -O "$(curl https://api.github.com/repos/casey/just/releases/latest | jq -r '.assets|last|.browser_download_url')"
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to do everything in `python` using standard library following way

```
import json, urllib.request
with urllib.request.urlopen('https://api.github.com/repos/casey/just/releases/latest') as response:
    url = json.load(response)["assets"][-1]["browser_download_url"]
fname = url.split('/')[-1]
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, fname)
```

Explanation: I use [`urllib.request`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) observe that `urlopen` does behave similiar to `open` but allows reading data via network, it can be used together with `json.load` same as with `open`. I extract desired URL, then create fname from last part of it and then I use `urlretrieve` to download file from `url` saving it under name `fname` inside current working directory.